# Has anyone used Neo4j node IDs as foreign keys to other databases for large property sets?

Tags: neo4j

I am building a large graph database that has a significant set of meta data about each node (thousands of properties per node).  I am currently going through the process of determining which meta data should be a node within Neo4j, which should become a property of the Node and which should be housed in a separate database.

My thinking is to use the meta data in 3 ways:
1 - If the property is shared between many nodes, to make that property it's own node and create an edge to that property.

2 - If the property is important to traversing the graph, but not "highly" shared, to add that as a node property.  (Which could also be indexed within Neo4j if needed)

3 = If the meta data is strictly describing that node, to have that stored in a separate NoSQL database, with the Neo4J Node ID becoming the foreign key to the other database.

While it seems like the most efficient use of using the graph database, it seems like a pain to have the different property types and having to determine which type of property it is before using it.  (Likely a property lookup key-value store) It would also likely mean that I would need an easy way to promote a property from 3 to 2 to 1 for instances when a property becomes highly shared, or needed for efficient traversal.

Has anyone taken this approach?  Any thoughts to share, or things to avoid?

Comment: I would not recommend using Neo4j ID's as they can be reused. This means you can delete and create a node and the new node could have the same node/relationship id as the old one. I've never personally seen this, however it is warned about in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Do never ever store a Neo4j node id in an external system. The node id is basically a offset in the respective store file. If you delete a node its id might be reused when new nodes are created.

The right approach is to have a "good" identifier (e.g. uuid) as a node property and put that into Neo4j's index. That uuid is then save to be stored in third party systems.

Some time ago I've created a unmanaged extension that adds a uuid to each new node and prevent manual changes to these uuids: https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid.

### Update (2013-08-21)

I've [blogged about UUIDs with Neo4j](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/08/assigning-uuids-to-neo4j-nodes-and-relationships/).

Comment: Great point that I hadn't thought about.  I was hardcoding my Neo4j node id's when they were created with an external ID, but that was giving me problems when I added other types of nodes, such as parameters as I could potentially have conflict.  I hadn't thought about deleting nodes.  So, assuming a I create a universal ID for each node, any thoughts about the 3 strata of properties?

Comment: stupid qustions: what do you refer to with "3 strata of properties"?

Comment: In the question I'm talking about stratifying properties into Nodes (Highest Level), Properties Of a Node (Second Level) and in a seperate database (Lowest Level).  Some meta-data properties would become neo4j nodes with edges to other nodes, others would become a property of a node, and lastly, the node would have a UUID that would reference another database to hold the property data.  I would then keep a property type reference table.  Does that make sense?